# Reformat wrapped data coerced into a dataframe? (R)

Tags: r, loops, format

I have some data I need to extract from a .txt file in a very weird, wrapped format. It looks like this:

```
       eid          nint    hisv    large       NA
1        1.00  1.00000e+00       0      1.0       NA
2  -152552.00 -6.90613e+04 -884198 -48775.7  1151.70
3    -5190.13  4.17751e-05      NA       NA       NA
4        2.00  1.00000e+00       0      1.0       NA
5  -172188.00 -8.16684e+04 -809131 -56956.1 -1364.07
6    -5480.54  4.01573e-05      NA       NA       NA
```

Luckily, I do not need all of this data. I just want to match `eid` with the value written in scientific notation. so:

```
   eid    sigma
1   1 4.17751e-005
2   2 4.01573e-005
3   3 3.72098e-005
```

This data goes on for hundreds of thousands of eids. It needs to discard the last three values of each first row, all of the values in row 2, and keep the last/second value in the third row. Then place it next to the 1st value of row 1. Then repeat. The column names other than 'eid' are totally disposable, too. I've never had to deal with wrapped data before so don't know where to begin.

**edited to show df after read-in.

Comment: Can you post the data exactly as it is after you read it in from the text file, you can use the `dput` command to do this.  What you listed above makes it difficult to tell if the file is fixed width or has some separator such as tabs.

Comment: Right, I have edited my original post.

Comment: `cbind(df[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(df), by = 3), "eid"],
      df[seq(from = 3, to = nrow(df), by = 3), "nint"])`

Comment: I realized that I need to preserve the original `eid` numbers since they in some cases don't follow numerical order. How can I retain that info?